# File responsed by response.download() and download as blob containing undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building a client-server certificate generator.

---

On **Backend**
I'm using two endpoints:

```
/
```

- Receives a JSON containing data extracted from inputs, sanitize them, and returns if they're valid or not

```
/download
```

- Receives whether data is valid or not. If it's, generate a `certificate.pdf` file and responses it with `res.download(certificatePath)`
- I guess I should use some kind of token/authentication/authorization because someone could just ignore the first endpoint but I'll do that once the downloading itself is fixed

I think the problem with backend is in some of those functions:

```js
const getCertificatePDF = (name, validValuesData, validValuesQty, response) => {
    // ... ommited for brevity
    pdf.create(document, options)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            let filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'certificate.pdf');
            console.log("FILE PATH: ", filePath);                            
            response.download(filePath, "certificate.pdf");
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
        });
}

app.post('/download', (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    console.log("DATA", data);
    getCertificatePDF(data.name, data.validValuesData, data.validValuesQty, res)
});
```

---

On **frontend**, I chained both requisitions using promises, created a `blob`, created a link with `download` attribute for that `blob` and triggered an`onClick`:

```js
const sendForm = (filledCodeValues, email, name) =>{
    // ...ommited for brevity

    fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: data,
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((processedData) => {
            alertAllFilledInvalid(processedData.validValuesQty)
            const dataString = JSON.stringify(processedData);
            if(processedData.validValuesQty > 0){
                console.log("DATA STRING ", dataString)
                const downloadUrl = url + "download";
                fetch(downloadUrl, {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: dataString,
                  })
                .then((res2) => {
                    res2.blob()
                })
                .then((blob)=>{
                    const newBlob = new Blob([blob]);
                    const newUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);

                    const link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.href = newUrl;
                    link.setAttribute('download', 'certificate.pdf');
                    document.body.appendChild(link);
                    link.click();
                    link.parentNode.removeChild(link);

                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(newBlob);
                })
            }
        })
}
```

---

### Issue

The issue is, the `certificate.pdf` downloaded by frontend is containing `undefined`:
[image: undefined certificate downloaded by frontend]

I know the first request is correct, because the `console.log()` is printing the expected contents for `stringData`:

[image: frontend manages to complete first request]

I also know the second request work, because on **backend, certificate.pdf is being correctly generated**:

[image: Backend receives second requisition correctly and generated pdf]

### Ps - i'm manually deleting `certificate.pdf` on backend to ensure it's a new one generated

Since certificate is being generated, I believe there's something wrong with either:

1. Backend's`response.download(filePath, "certificate.pdf");`
2. FrontEnd blob creating and downloading

I manually moved `certificate(25).pdf` (generated by frontend) to backend and run a script for reading both `certificate.pdf`(generated by backend) files, to test if the issue is on `filePath` using a `readFiles.js` script:

```
const fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');

let filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'certificate.pdf');
console.log("FILE PATH: ", filePath);
fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(">>>>> FilePath content <<<<< ", data);
});


let filePath2 = path.join(__dirname, 'certificate(25).pdf');
console.log("FILE PATH 2: ", filePath2);
fs.readFile(filePath2, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(">>>> FilePath2 content <<<< ", data);
});
```

[image: readFiles]

It turns out the path is correct, and `certificate.pdf (backend)` has content, while `certificate(25).pdf (frontend)` has just an `undefined` value.

---

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the value of `res2.blob()`:

```
.then((res2) => {
  return res2.blob()
})
```

Or leave out the brackets:

```
.then((res2) => res2.blob())
```

Comment: God, it worked!!!!! Thank you very much! I spent almost 10 hours trying to fix it and would never have guessed it! I'll mark as right answer as soon as stackoverflow allows me